# How to check how many messages a user has sent in a server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to do this for an XP system that runs by how many messages sent. Each message is 5 XP but I haven't figured out how to find the number of messages sent by a user (in a server). Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the welcoming... But I'm mainly after how I can check. I'm not really asking for the code to be written. How do I say this, I'm looking for the line that would check for this. e.g `guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === '---')` However, I do understand that the question can be taken as I'm hunting for someone to spoon-feed me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to do this is to look at **every** message in the guild and count them one by one.
There are a few optimization tricks you can use, like not looking at messages sent before the user joined ([`GuildMember.joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt)), but it's still a huge operation because you'll ultimately need to fetch every message in the guild.

The search feature in Discord could be useful in this situation, but it's not currently available in Discord.js (or to bot users at all).

I think the best thing for you to do is not to do it at all: it's better if you keep a database with every user's exp level, and update their exp on every message (or once a day, if you prefer).
Not keeping a database at all is not a viable solution, since you'd need to fetch the entire guild every time (and I think you'd get rate-limited at that point).
If you were trying to do this only once to establish the initial level for everyone then it's better if you do something based on the time since they've joined the guild, or just make start everyone from 0.
There's an exception though: if you think your guild is small enough you can fetch all the messages just one time but at that point, you may just make everyone start at 0, it's much simpler.

Comment: Oh... Thanks for the detailed explanation. I might try getting a database. Any recommendations?

Comment: You're welcome :). Regarding the database: the number of options is really endless, and the answer might vary a lot depending on the scope of your bot. If you're just building a bot for your own guild, then keep it simple and just use a JSON file, where the bot can periodically save the database. Unless you're going to have millions of entries and high access rates, you're not really going to get much benefit from using one database over the other, you may as well keep it as basic as possible.